# How to initialize an array of the first ten integers briefly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby

I'm studying Ruby and JavaScript. Occasionally I want an array of the first ten integers (or some other predictable series):

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

In Ruby, is there a faster (like, built in) way to initialize this array than `(0..9).to_a`? Anyway, that's pretty fast.

But in JavaScript, I don't know of any similarly fast way to build it. I could iterate over a `for` loop but I figure there has to be a faster way. But what is it?

Comment: `Array.from(Array(10).keys())` - JS.

Comment: In Ruby you can also do `[*0..9]`

Comment: Ruby: `Array.new(10, &:itself)`.

Comment: What is your definition of _faster_? _Faster_ to type (aka shorter), _faster_ to read (easy to understand) or the code runs _faster_ (low memory consumption, fewer cycles - benchmarked)?

Comment: Good question. But I meant faster to type.

Comment: Changed "How to initialize an array of the first ten integers faster than this?" to "How to initialize an array of the first ten integers briefly?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `spread syntax` in combination with `keys()` method.

```js
console.log([ ...Array(10).keys() ]);
```

Another way is to use `Array.from` method.

```js
console.log(Array.from({length: 10}, (_, k) => k));
```

Comment: I was thinking it would involve the spread operator, I just didn't see how. Now I know!